# Jquery get updated table elements after DOM .append .after

Tags: jquery, dom, html-table, append

In short, I need to get the first column data from the table, including rows appended with jQuery.

Below is my code using jQuery to add a row to a HTML table. It all works as expected, however the variable `firstColumns` (which collects values from the first columns of the table) does not include the appended rows from additional clicks of the 'Add Row' button. 
 Additional rows will need data of all columns including all appended, hoping someone knows how to get this data from the refreshed DOM?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#add").on("click", function() {

    var firstColumns = [];

    $("table#personalPrices tr").each(function() {
      var val = $(this).find("th:first").text();
      firstColumns.push(val);
    });

    var existingRow = $('table#personalPrices tbody>tr:nth-child(1)').next('tr');

    var newRow = '<tr><td>4 + 23</td><td>test3</td></tr>';

    existingRow.after(newRow);

    console.log(firstColumns);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="personalPrices">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1 + 23</th>
      <td>test1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3 + 23</th>
      <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="add">Add Row</button>
```

Comment: You are adding new row with  `<td>` and your function that fills `firstColumns` is looking for `<th>`. So you want this: `var newRow = '<tr><th>4 + 23</th><td>test3</td></tr>';` Or you change every `<th>` to `<td>` and find for `"td:first"`

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @calvin-nunes you are adding only `<td>` but at the same time you are trying to find `<th>`. In this case you should simply update your code as follows:

```js
$("#add").on("click", function() {
    var firstColumns = [];
  debugger;

    $("table#personalPrices tr").each(function() {
      var val = $(this).find("th:first").text();
      firstColumns.push(val);
    });

    var existingRow = $('table#personalPrices tbody>tr:nth-child(1)').next('tr');

    var newRow = '<tr><th>4 + 23</th><td>test3</td></tr>';

    existingRow.after(newRow);

    console.log(firstColumns);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="personalPrices">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1 + 23</th>
      <td>test1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3 + 23</th>
      <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="add">Add Row</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#add").on("click", function() {
    var existingRow = $('table#personalPrices tbody>tr:nth-child(1)').next('tr');

    var newRow = '<tr><td>4 + 23</td><td>test3</td></tr>';

    existingRow.after(newRow);
    var firstColumns = [];

    $("#personalPrices tr").each(function() {
      var val = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").html();
      firstColumns.push(val);
    });

    console.log(firstColumns);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="personalPrices">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1 + 23</td>
      <td>test1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3 + 23</td>
      <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="add">Add Row</button>
```

Comment: Only posting a code without any explanation is not a good answer, Please read [answer]

Comment: he/she can ask for explanation if they need . @CalvinNunes

Comment: It's not like that how SO works... have you read the link I posted in the comment?
But, ok, it's up to you, the downvote stays

Comment: hahhaha have you really downvoted many of my answers? ok, keep going, you are using StackOverflow in the right way, congratulations. It's easier to downvote my answers than respect the [answer] , and add a simple explanation...